# Distribute items evenly through pipes

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

Is there a equivalent pipe to Tekkit's "distribution transport pipe" for FTB Unleashed? I know diamond pipes will split items if a specific item is allowed on multiple exits/colors. The problem is I have much more then 9 items to handle and I want to distribute those items equally to my machines processing them. So I need something like the distribution transport pipe in Tekkit that allows to distribute all incoming material equally.

Comment: If you chain multiple such junctions together, won't that work? ie. handle all you want to handle in the first, and sending the rest to another junction?

Answer (score 1):

Distribution pipes were initially removed because they were out of date, however the add-on "additional-pipes" is now available for the latest version of FTB, which contains distribution pipes.

The alternative is a bit of a convoluted mess of diamond pipes, or you could look into the redpower2 sorting machine.